# How do I scrape specific images (excluding thumbnails,icons,etc.) from forums using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

For example I want to get links of all images of the forum http://www.xossip.com/showthread.php?t=1384077.

When I inspect the pictures (big ones from forum post) they have something like this in commomn `<img src="http://pzy.be/i/5/17889.jpg" border="0" alt="">`.

What should the program be to list all the URLs of the required images. If possible to even download them.

I've tried a little bit of code but got stucked.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.xossip.com/showthread.php?t=1384077&page=' + str(page)
        sourcecode= requests.get(url)
        plaintext = sourcecode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plaintext)
        for link in soup.findAll('img src'):
            print (link)
        page += 1
spider(1)
```

**EDIT**
I want the images in the forum but i want to avoid all those small thumbnails , logos , icons etc etc . i have observed that all the images i need have this format in common `<img src="http://pzy.be/i/5/17889.jpg" border="0" alt="">`
so i need all the links of the images in above format ,so i need the program to go through all the pages of forum , refine images with src , border=0 , alt and finally print all the image urls , like pzy.be/i/5/452334.jpg

Comment: Please, post code here, and see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry im new here and im having trouble to understand how to paste code here

Comment: @sobolevn done added

Answer (score 1):

Try use `tag.get('src')` instead of `soup.findAll('img src')`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.xossip.com/showthread.php?t=1384077&page=' + str(page)
        sourcecode= requests.get(url)
        plaintext = sourcecode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plaintext)

        for tag in soup.findAll('img'): 
            print(tag.get('src'))   # use `tag.get('src')` in this case

        page += 1
spider(1)
```

Please check [the document](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for more details.

---

If you need download them, you could also use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) to download the image's content, and write it into a file. Here's a demo:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.xossip.com/showthread.php?t=1384077&page=' + str(page)
        sourcecode= requests.get(url)
        plaintext = sourcecode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plaintext)

        for tag in soup.findAll('img'):
            link = tag.get('src')  # get the link

            # Check if the tag is in expect format
            del tag['src']
            if tag.attrs != {';': '', 'alt': '', 'border': '0'}:
                continue

            filename = link.strip('/').rsplit('/', 1)[-1]  # to get the correct file name

            image = requests.get(link).content  # use requests to get the content of the images
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(image)  # write the image into a file

        page += 1
spider(1)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Taarush/PycharmProjects/First/first.py", line 13, in <module>
    spider(1)
  File "/Users/Taarush/PycharmProjects/First/first.py", line 6, in spider
    sourcecode= requests.get(url)
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined

Comment: @TaarushV You forgot `import requests`, huh?

Comment: Thanks it did work . but i just want images which are the big ones not the icons and thumbnails , i just want the ones whuch have <img src="http://pzy.be/i/6/17885.jpg" border="0" alt=""> . you know like border "0" . how do i get them specifically , Thanks again

Comment: @TaarushV: So, get all images which has `border="0"` for example?

Comment: i mean the images i want excluding icons etc have border="0" and alt="" and pzy.be host common . i should i filter them within the code

Comment: @TaarushV: Oh, get images, only has `src`. For example: Get `<img src="pzy.be/i/6/17885.jpg">`, but not `<img src="pzy.be/i/6/17885.jpg"; border="0" alt="">`. Right?

Comment: oh no i mean i need to get the link of images which have <img src="XYZ"; border="0" alt="">.
i need the XYZ in this context only

Comment: @TaarushV: Well I still little don't understand... But what about edit the question and mention these in your original question?